# How can I automatically format hyperlink text in Word/Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I like adding hyperlinks to my Word documents and e-mails in Outlook.  I usually prefer to change the link `Text to display` to something more readable than just the URL.  I follow patterns for some URLs.  For example, we have a [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) wiki, and I usually reformat the link text from

```
https://host/confluence/display/space/Some+Wiki+Page
```

to

```
Our Wiki - Some Wiki Page
```

Granted, the URL itself is fairly descriptive, but I still prefer a text form.  I also like to format other links in this manner (for example, `Amazon.com - Some Product`).

Is there a way to create automatic rules for doing this formatting when pasting a link?  Perhaps in a macro?

I will also accept an answer if there is a way to automatically bring up the `Insert Hyperlink` dialog when I paste a link.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will paste a link you have in clipboard, to TextToDisplay="**ref**". Which you may edit in the macro to whatever you want, and make multiple macros with different TextToDisplay.

Someone could probably easily make this recognize a domain and preformat the text. But I had no need, so haven't done that.

To run this macro you must include a reference:

Tools > References > Browse > ..Windows\System32\FM20.dll , Open, OK
(Adds MS Forms 2.0 Object Library)

This was done in Word 2003, so no promise for other versions, but will probably work.

For example, I made one called hyperlink_yt, which I use for youtube links with TextToDisplay="yt", assigned shortcut Alt+Y to this macro.

```
Sub hyperlink_ref()
' Makes clipboard-hyperlink ref
Dim MyData As DataObject
Dim strClip As String
Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.GetFromClipboard
strClip = MyData.GetText
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=strClip, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="ref"
End Sub
```